# Remembering the select field value

Tags: php, html

```
public static function load_months()
{
    $output = "\n <select id='month' name='month'>";
    $output .= "\n <option value='0'>Month</option>";

    for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++)
    {
        $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10, 1980);
        $monthName = date("F", $timestamp);
        $output .= "\n <option value='$i'>$monthName</option>";
    }

    $output .= "\n </select>";
    echo($output);
}
```

I've made this above code to display select of month names. i want to make this script remember the posted selected option just like my name field below from session array. How to do this?

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?= $user_data->first_name ?>" placeholder="First Name" required>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to make use of the "selected" attribute of the option element.

```
public static function load_months($user_data = null)
{
    $output = "\n <select id='month' name='month'>";
    $output .= "\n <option value='0'>Month</option>";

    for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++)
    {
        $selected = ( !is_null($user_data) && isset($user_data->month) && $user_data->month == $i ? 'selected="selected"' : '' );
        $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10, 1980);
        $monthName = date("F", $timestamp);
        $output .= sprintf("\n <option value='%s' %s>%s</option>",$i,$selected,$monthName);
    }

    $output .= "\n </select>";
    echo($output);
}
```

Yet, if you're concerned about scalability. You could do something like this

```
public static function load_months($selectedMonth = null)
{

    $output = "\n <select id='month' name='month'>";
    $output .= "\n <option value='0'>Month</option>";

    for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++)
    {
        $selected = ( !is_null($selectedMonth) && is_numeric($selectedMonth) && $selectedMonth == $i ? 'selected="selected"' : '' );
        $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10, 1980);
        $monthName = date("F", $timestamp);
        $output .= sprintf("\n <option value='%s' %s>%s</option>",$i,$selected,$monthName);
    }

    $output .= "\n </select>";
    echo($output);
}
```

And you'll simply pass the selected month to the method.

Comment: It's not working bro. i'm trying your method but every time i post my form with selecting some month from the drop down it get still the same 'month'

Comment: Are you remembering to pass either a month or a user_data element to the function?

Comment: i'm remembering the passing month that is stored in a class data member and then if the user selected in registration form and mistakenly got error in some field then the field remember it's last given month not to reset itself

Comment: i understand. But when you call the "load_months()" method. You must pass that month that you are remembering. Etc.  echo $class->load_month(3);

Answer (score 0):

Pass the selected value as a parameter to the function-

```
public static function load_months($selected)
{
    $output = "\n <select id='month' name='month'>";
    $output .= "\n <option value='0'>Month</option>";

    for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++)
    {
        $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10, 1980);
        $monthName = date("F", $timestamp);
         if($i==$selected)
      {
        $output .= "\n <option value='$i' selected='selected'>$monthName</option>";
      }
       else
      {
           $output .= "\n <option value='$i'>$monthName</option>";
       }
    }

    $output .= "\n </select>";
    echo($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if (isset($user_data->month) && $user_data->month == $i) {
            $output .= "\n <option selected='selected' value='$i'>$monthName</option>";
} else {
            $output .= "\n <option value='$i'>$monthName</option>";
}
```